# Spring Testing Mock MVC doesn't apply custom RequestMappingHandlerMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, mockmvc

I have created a Custom annotation to version my APIs.

Everything works when running the application.

However when I try to test my controllers using `MockMvc`, the custom `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` I wrote isn't being applied.

I'm initializing `MockMvc` like this

```
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
            .apply(documentationConfiguration(this.restDocumentation))
            .apply(springSecurity())
            .build();
    }
```

I override the defaults to use my custom `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` like this

```
@Configuration
public class RoutingConfig {
    @Bean
    public WebMvcRegistrations webMvcRegistrationsPathHandlerMapping() {
        return new WebMvcRegistrations() {
            @Override
            public RequestMappingHandlerMapping getRequestMappingHandlerMapping() {
                return new APIPathRequestHandlerMapping();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Any idea what's going on? I thought the web application context initialization of the `MockMvc` would pick up all the configuration changes by default.

EDIT 1:

I should also add that I'm using Spring Boot 2.1.2.RELEASE

EDIT 2:
To clarify, the versioning annotation when applied to a controller accepts request that starts with the version, i.e: `/users` becomes `/v1/users`

This works with normal requests are coming up, but for tests only `/users` work, `/v1/users` returns a 404 (Not found)

I've placed debug points in the configs and the custom `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` and am sure that this is not being picked up by `MockMvc`.

I've tried to autowire MockMvc, but the same behaviour persists, with the additional issue of not being able to configure Spring RestDocs.

Comment: If you're using Boot, it's usually better to autowire your MockMvc, which ensures that you get a configuration that closely matches your real runtime.

Comment: @chrylis I am using boot, however autowiring doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **@AutoConfigureMockMvc** Annotation that can be applied to a test class to enable and configure auto-configuration of MockMvc.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {        
        System.out.println("test "+mockMvc);
    }
}
```

Note: I applied custom RequestMappingHandlerMapping, it is getting applied with MockMvc autoconfiguration successfully.

Comment: This doesn't work. I tried this and the behaviour is the same

Comment: which code would you like to see? I'll be happy to post more code if that'll help.

Comment: I've also added some clarifications to the original question, hope that helps shed some light, apologies if I wasn't very clear in the original question content.

Comment: This is the best solution. If it "doesn't work", then debugging *why* it doesn't work is the way to go.

Comment: @chrylis After your comment I tried again and it worked, as for why it didn't before, I have no clue :-|

Answer (score 0):

You can import any custom configuration class in the spring test using

```
@Import(value = YourCofigClassName.class)
```